# Saving file with part of file name and date

Tags: matlab, date, file-io, save, filenames

Hi there I'm currently trying to find a way to save 2 variables from my workspace into a file.  I want the file name to be put together using the original and the current date.

I only want the max value from the variables so:

```
max(streaking)
```

and

```
max(tap_total)
```

The original file name is:

3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1_PRI_PRI_PRI_PRI_15_17_ActivePixelMeans.csv

The only portion of this original file name that I would like to use is:

```
3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1
```

These can be saved in a text file or spreadsheet, it doesnt matter.

An example of the new file name would be something like this:

```
3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1_7-26-2012
```

Also,

If something could be done in the file to display which variable is which, for example:

```
Streaking: 1.272  % this would come from the variable max(streaking)

Tap_Total: 2.252  % this would come from the varaible max(tap_total)
```

EDIT:

```
% Construct a questdlg with three options

choice = questdlg('Would you like to save?', ...

'Save Options', ...

'Yes','No','Cancel','Cancel');

% Handle response

switch choice

case 'Yes'

    disp([choice ' processing.'])

    save_option = 1;
case 'No'
    disp([choice ' processing.'])
    save_option = 0;
case 'Cancel'
    disp('Canceled.')
    save_option = 2;
end

file_to_get = evalin( 'base', 'file_to_get' );
streaking = evalin( 'base', 'streaking' );
tap_total = evalin( 'base', 'tap_total' );

if save_option == 0
elseif save_option == 1

    max_streak = max(streaking);
    max_tap = max(tap_total);
    str_streak = mat2str(max_streak);
    str_tap = mat2str(max_tap);
    fname = file_to_get;
    pruned_fname = regexprep(fname,'_PRI(\w*).(\w*)','');
    new_fname = [pruned_fname '_' date '.csv'];
    path1 = '\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\analysis data\Banding and Streaking Results';
    fid = fopen([path1 new_fname], 'w');
    fprintf(fid,['Max Banding: %s\nMax Streaking: %s'],str_tap,str_streak)
    fclose(fid);
elseif save_option == 2
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a great place to use the `regexprep` command to prune the original filename down.

Example:

```
fname = '3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1_PRI_PRI_PRI_PRI_15_17_ActivePixelMeans.csv';
pruned_fname = regexprep(fname,'_PRI(\w*).(\w*)','');

pruned_fname =

3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1
```

Now, a note about the `regexprep` command I used here.  This is specific for the filename you provided here.  Since it looks like you want to trim off everything after the the first `_PRI` I used a tag  `(\w*)` which means any combination of `[a-z A-Z _ 0-9]` can follow.  Notice that since this is a filename there is a `.` there hence why I added a period in and followed that with another `(\w*)` to finish out the csv.  You can find more info on these sorts of operators [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html).

Now that you have the `pruned_fname` you can simply add whatever you want to it.  So if you want to add the date in with an underscore to space it just simply do something like this:

```
new_fname = [pruned_fname '_' date '.csv'];
new_fname =

3_FM001_02_05460$BandP$64_24000_FWD_1x1csv_26-Jul-2012.csv
```

Now you simply need to open the file to write to it.  you might need to append the path to where you want to save it, I'm just going to call it `path` for now.  It would be something like `C:\Documents\`

```
fid = fopen([path new_fname], 'w')
```

Now with the `fid` you have the id of the file you want to write to.  This should be a new file and if it isn't you are going to overwrite the file contents if you do it this way.  Just be aware =)

Next you can simply write those first two lines to the file using `fwrite` `fprintf`, just to name a few possible functions.

Hopefully that'll get you setup there!

Comment: Okay, so I'm just using the workspace variable that I'm creating "file_to_get" to supplement fname. And this works perfectly fine. It is creating the new file name perfectly. it's just telling me that i need to use fopen, when i am. I've added the path which i assumed is the correct thing to do.  This is while trying to use fprintf.  When i try to use fwrite, it does not save anything, but no errors are given.

Comment: If you update your question with how you're using `fwrite` and `fprintf` I might be able to lend a better hand.  Just give an example of how you're trying to write in the two lines of info you mentioned at the end of the original question.  You're probably not too far off.

Comment: See my edit, I am trying to prompt the user with an option box of whether they wish to save or not.

Comment: Okay, so It is working, just not properly.  It is saving the new files in the folder before the end one in the path variable.  And then it is tacking on the end folder as a prefix to the name of the file.  My current fix to this is just creating a new folder inside the one i want, designating it as my path, and just naming it something that doesnt affect the file name.  So if you do know the solution to this, that would be great, but it's not 100% necessary.  Thanks for the help and great description of the solution :)

Comment: You just need to add another `\ (slash)` at the end of your path.  Then it should be saving to the location you want.  So it'll look like this: `path1 = '\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\analysis data\Banding and Streaking Results\'`

Comment: Ahh, that would make sense, such a minor little thing to over look haha, thanks again